# Visual studio 2015 remove uninstalled bower packages from wwwroot?

Tags: bower, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to have a grunt task clean wwwroot from any removed bower packages?

Answer (score 1):

the [grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean) do the job well
Or set cleanTargetDir in the grunt bower task:

```
bower: {
        install: {
            options: {
                targetDir: "wwwroot/lib",
                layout: "byComponent",
                cleanTargetDir: true
            }
        }
    },
```